# Boxspring fitting on an antique 4 poster bed

Tags: bedroom

I just put my four poster bed back together after many years and the boxspring lip is sitting on top of the side rails but I feel that it is supposed to go down inside the side rails and sit on the inside lip but it doesn’t seem like the four posters are wide enough for this to happen, but the mattress shows if it is sitting on top of the sideboards. Where does it go? Thank you

Comment: Would think inside so there is a stop to keep it from sliding over.  Was the boxspring bought for the bed dimensions, or just bought online/store as a close fit?  Will find sizes of old and new stuff do not always match.

Comment: how about a photo

Comment: Can check this question.  The answer with the slats might work for you, without needing to get a new boxspring.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/25996/how-can-i-update-this-very-stubborn-antique-bed-frame-so-the-mattress-fits-prope?rq=1

Comment: How do I add a photo? The mattress was made for bed and came with it.

Comment: I think you use the edit button and look for a mountain icon to add photos.